# Kinetic energy in Jacobi coordinates

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, reference-frames, coordinate-systems

I should express the momentum of the system of $N$ particles and the kinetic energy in terms of Jacobi coordinates:
$$\vec \xi_n = \frac{m_1 \vec r_1+\dots+m_n\vec r_n}{m_1+\dots+m_n}-\vec r_{n+1}, \quad (n=1,\dots, N-1),  $$
$$\vec \xi_N = \frac{m_1 \vec r_1+\dots+ m_N \vec r_N}{m_1+\dots+m_N }.$$
So, I've already found the momentum:
$$ \vec \xi_N = \frac{m_1 \vec r_1+\dots+ m_N \vec r_N}{m_1+\dots+m_N }=
\frac{ \vec p_1+\dots+  \vec p_N}{m_1+\dots+m_N }= \frac{ \vec P}{m_1+\dots+m_N }
\Rightarrow 
\boxed{
\vec P= \vec \xi_N \sum_i^N m_i}
 $$
But how I can find the kinetic energy? I've already tried to write it as a quadratic form and subsequently change variables in it, but I cannot inverse the transformation matrix...
The correct answer from the book is  $T= \frac{1}{2}\sum_{n=1}^N \mu_n \dot \xi_n^2$, where $\frac{1}{\mu_n}=\frac{1}{\sum_{k=1}^n m_k}+\frac{1}{m_{n+1}}, (n=1,\dots, N-1)$.

Comment: A good book illustrating these types of coordinate transforms is Molecular Vibrations by Wilson, Decius, and Cross. They illustrate how to hope between momentum and velocity perspectives in non-rectangular coordinate systems used in molecular vibration analysis.

Answer (score 0):

Since this is a homework question, the Physics SE members must not provide the complete answer which solves it. Check [this](https://books.google.com/books?id=dK-fl0KrOEIC&pg=PA9) link and generalize lemma 1.6 from the three body case to the N body case. Alternately, since the expected expression and proof for the three body case is known, you may write a proof by induction showing that it is indeed the accurate expression.